# MySQL Query to get the monthly data difference

Tags: mysql

```
select * from new_joiner;
+------+--------------+
| id   | date_of_join |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | 2020-01-10   |
|    2 | 2020-01-02   |
|    3 | 2020-01-05   |
|    4 | 2020-02-10   |
|    5 | 2020-02-11   |
|    6 | 2020-07-11   |
|    7 | 2020-07-11   |
|    8 | 2020-07-11   |
|    9 | 2020-07-11   |
|   10 | 2020-07-11   |
|   11 | 2020-05-01   |
|   12 | 2020-05-02   |
|   13 | 2020-05-03   |
|   14 | 2020-05-04   |
|   15 | 2020-05-05   |
|   16 | 2020-05-05   |
|   17 | 2020-05-06   |
+------+--------------+


select   MONTHNAME(date_of_join) as MONTHNAME, 
         count(id) as JOINEE 
from     new_joiner 
where    MONTH(date_of_join)>=1 
group by MONTH(date_of_join);
+-----------+--------+
| MONTHNAME | JOINEE |
+-----------+--------+
| January   |      3 |
| February  |      2 |
| May       |      7 |
| July      |      5 |
+-----------+--------+
```

I want a query that gives me the monthly data change compare to previous month.

For example: new joinee in Jan was 3, and in Feb it was 2, so compare to Jan in Feb month -1 joined, so the query should output me:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| MONTHNAME | JOINEE_DIFF |
+-----------+-------------+
| February  |          -1 |
| Mar       |          -2 |
| April     |           0 |
| May       |           7 |
| June      |          -7 |
| July      |           5 |
| Aug       |          -5 |
| Sep       |           0 |
| Oct       |           0 |
| Nov       |           0 |
| Dec       |           0 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Ignore Jan as it doesn't have a previous month and assume we have data only for a given year say 2020. Require data for all months from Feb to Dec.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas it MySQL 5.6

Comment: There are no rows for April. So for May you calculate the difference between May and Fefruary. Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi @forpas assume we have data for each month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data for every month, you can use `lag()`:

```
select MONTHNAME(date_of_join) as MONTHNAME, 
       count(id) as JOINEE,
       (count(*) - lag(count(*)) over (order by  min(date_of_join)) as diff
from new_joiner 
where MONTH(date_of_join) >= 1 
group by MONTH(date_of_join);
```

Note that using months without years if fraught with peril.  Also, the `month()` of any well-formed date should be larger than 1.

All this suggests a query more like:

```
select *
from (select MONTHNAME(date_of_join) as MONTHNAME, 
             count(id) as JOINEE,
             (count(*) - lag(count(*)) over (order by  min(date_of_join)) as diff,
             min(date_of_join) as min_date_of_join
      from new_joiner 
      where date_of_join >= '2020-01-01' and date_of_join < '2021-01-01'
      group by MONTH(date_of_join)
     ) t
where diff is not null
order by min_date_of_join;
```

Comment: Hi I tried you queries none of them worked. I am using MySQL 5.6.x

Comment: These require MySQL 8+.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery to get the number of joinees of previous month and subtract it:

```
SELECT 
  t.monthname,
  joinee - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM new_joiner WHERE MONTH(date_of_join) = t.month - 1) JOINEE_DIFF 
FROM (
  SELECT MONTH(date_of_join) month, MONTHNAME(date_of_join) monthname, 
         COUNT(id) joinee 
  FROM new_joiner 
  GROUP BY month, monthname
) t 
WHERE t.month > 1;
```

Comment: Hi @forpas your query looks fine require small change as we don't have any data for Mar and April months so it should display data for these month as well. I mean we need data from Feb to Dec months.

Comment: This is your answer from a question I asked under your question: *assume we have data for each month*